# Internal Server Error Uploading Images mod_php VS cgi

Tags: php, apache

I am using the JAVA Applet known as Rad Upload - http://www.radinks.com/upload/ the APPLET crashes an generates an Internal Server Error.

We made all the adjustments both Apache and PHP to upload larger images. This is the issue. There seems to be an issue with PHP itself. We made an exact duplicate of the upload scripting on another server. One works and their other does not.

The one that works
PHP Version 5.2.5 running as Apache

The one that is not working
PHP Version 5.2.13 running as CGI

According to the hosting company there is no error logs say what is the issue. They can see that the images are being Posted, and when it comes time to run the Upload Scripting it crashes before it even accesses this.

**Even though this isn't the issue here is the upload script.**
Please note this is not the final upload scripting being used. This is a strip down version for testing - even this stripped down does not work. We have gone to the point of using a blank upload script with no PHP at all. And still get the internal server error with logs being produced.

```
session_start();
$photo = $_FILES['userfile'];
$count = count($photo['name']);
if (!is_dir('./'.$_SESSION['order'])) {
    mkdir('./'.$_SESSION['order']);
}
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    move_uploaded_file($photo['tmp_name'][$i], './'.$_SESSION['order']/'.$photo['name'][$i]);
}
```

The web site has been moved to another newer server and the same issue. I believe it has something to do with PHP running as CGI. As this is the only difference between both scenarios.

Does this make any sense and has anyone seen this?

Comment: +1 to @Marc B's comments.  I really don't understand why you using a paid-for closed-source product here.  This solution is ripe for attack.  How do you prevent someone re-engineering this and exploiting this as an upload repository.  You also need  to scrub the images to prevent exploits.

Comment: Please read my comment below. Forget about the upload script. This has been stripped down to an absolute minimum to determine if it is the scripting or the server. The scripting is even blank - no php as well and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. PHP was not compiled correctly. After moving me to a new server ... bam! Uploading works.

For those concerned about the security, thank you for your comments. Yes it has all been put back.

Answer (score 2):

You have not checked if the upload actually succeeded in your code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if ($photo['error'][$i] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        if (!move_uploaded_file($photo['tmp_name'][$i], './'.$_SESSION['order']/'.$photo['name'][$i])) {
            echo "Unable to move file #$i to final destination";
        }
    } else {
       echo "Upload #$i failed with error code ", $photo['error'][$i];
    }
}
```

Note that your code is also vulnerable to a file scribbling attack. You're blindly using the user-provided `['name']` portion, which CAN include file pathing information. It would be utterly trivial for a malicious user to set the filename to something like `../../../../../../../../etc/passwd`, allowing them to scribble on any file on your server which the webserver process has write access to.

Comment: The upload script published above is protected. That is a stripped down version. I have gone as far as making the PHP script blank. It isn't the upload script. The error is generated before it even reaches this stage. I am sure I wrote that above that it isn't the scripting. It seems to come down to one sever running as mod_php and the other as cgi. We have tested everything.

Comment: What happens if you just do a regular post to the script, with no file upload at all (e.g. remove the file input and use the default enctype)? Do other PHP scripts run ok?

Comment: I regular post and all other scripting works. I still do not think it is PHP scripting itself. We did try it as a blank upload page. It stalls out before it reaches this based on testing it.

Comment: @Tim, One of the first places to start is the access logs (nearly all shared hosting providers make them available.)  Also my point about the Rad product being closed-source is that it's a black box as far as you are concerned.  Instrument the working version to retro-engineer its API then implement a client-side test stub using Perl/PHP whatever and then use this to debug the new server side: both ends will then be open and able to be instrumented.